# SocketException trying to connect to server "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time"

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, client

I have a server, which is simply a program that listens on a port of my computer. I have a client program, to, that connects to this port, sends requests and gets responses. For this I use the `System.Net.Socket` class, with the tcp protocol.

The problem is that my client can connect when the server is on the same computer, but when I give the client to someone else, it doesn't work. SocketException : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
I don't understand, but as I am just beginning, I think something's hiding from me...

Here is my code:

Client:

```
private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sock.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip.Text), 1234));
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    read();
                }).Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Manage exception
            }
        }

private void read()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
                    int rec = sock.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                    if (rec <= 0)
                        throw new SocketException();

                    Array.Resize(ref buffer, rec);

                    //Displaying received data
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        requests.Items.Add(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
                    });
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("DISCONNECTED");
                    sock.Close();
                    break;
                }
            }

            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Server:

```
private void Listen()
        {
            server.Listen(0);

            new Thread(AcceptOneConnection).Start();
        }

private void AcceptOneConnection()
        {
            if (client != null)
                client.Close();

            client = server.Accept();

            MessageBox.Show("Client accepted");

            while (true)
            {
                string received = ReceiveData();

                if (received == "stop connection")
                    break;

                string[] request = received.Split(' ');

                switch (request[0])
                {
                    case "register":
                        Register(request);
                        break;
                    case "login":
                        Login(request);
                        break;
                    case "disconnect":
                        UsersManager.Disconnect();
                        SendData("Disconnected");
                        break;
                    default:
                        SendData("Unknown request");
                        break;
                }
            }

            client.Close();
        }

private string ReceiveData()
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
                int rec = client.Receive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0);

                if (rec <= 0)
                    throw new SocketException();

                Array.Resize(ref buffer, rec);

                return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
            }
            catch
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

What should I change to make someone in possession of the client able to connect to the server?